# Alternative greedy strategy to finding points in intervals: does this approach work?

Tags: algorithm, intervals, greedy

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> You are given a collection of intervals. Find the smallest number of points such that each interval contains at least one point.

I know that one solution to this problem is to sort the intervals by their end time, then to greedily repeatedly pick the endpoint of the earliest interval not yet covered and add that to the result.

However, it also got to my mind that it could be solved by choosing the point which eliminates more intervals at once. I know this idea is not correct, but I cannot find any counterexample. Can someone help me find a counterexample to this strategy?

Comment: could you specify more precisely the problem?

Comment: Sure! Sorry. I have a set of intervals [x1,x2] and I want to find the minimum number of points which can cover all intervals.

For example, I have:
[1,5], [3,7] and [4,5]

So the answer in here would be two points: 3 and 4 for example.

Comment: @maria: 1 point: 4 will cover these 3 intervals

Comment: Okay sorry you are right I made a quick example. But my question is another. Sorry! First time using the platform, a bit messy for me.

Comment: and if you can also precise what do you mean by "eliminates more intervals at once"

Comment: I mean that this point we pick, it contains a number X of intervals. So, the idea is that I do not have to consider these X intervals when picking another number.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example assuming the intervals are inclusive.

Take intervals:

`[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [4, 7], [5, 8], [5, 9], [5, 10], [8, 12]`

Greedy will put a point in 5 as it has the most intervals (all of them except two) Then it will put a point somewhere in the interval `[1, 4]` and another in the interval `[8, 12]`.

Greedy's answer is 3. But the optimal way is to put one point in 4 and one point in 8 and they all will be covered.

Edit: draw the intervals on a paper for better understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Counterexample:

```
[-----]         [-----]
[------------]
        [-------------]
[------------]
        [-------------]
```

Comment: Some (verbal) explanation may make this answer *far* more understandable to the many mere mortals that frequent this site!